# need help using dotnotnuke modal

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to call dnn modal on click of a link by passing string query parameter to the link in   other to retreive from information from the page linking to.  here is my href code:

```
    <a href="javascript:dnnModal.show('<%#DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL("/ViewFleetTerminal","Id=" + Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString()) + "?popUp=true" %>',false,550,950,true)">Click Me!</a>

modal appear without any content.  and  if i point my mouse to the   link, this is the url that its  showing

    javascript:dnnModal.show(''?popUp=true,false,550,950,true)
Please is there anyone that can help. thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check in the html page that the required URL was actually rendered, if it's not try the `'<%=` instead of `'<%#`

Also, try to call the NavigateURL method by providing the tabId (the page id) without any other params like this:

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(tabId)
```

this dhould get you to the default page

And finally, the popup JS call:

```
var url= ...
dnnModal.show(url + '?popUp=true', /*showReturn*/false, 550, 950, true, '');
```